# Trigger a VBScript when a file is added to a folder

Tags: file, vbscript, directory

I wish to automate some tasks.  I need to move files from one folder to another.  I have written the script below which is working fine.

But my requirement is to trigger this VB script automatically, in the background, when a file is created or added to a folder.

```
'Script Begins

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    .MoveFile "C:\Source\Files\*.*", "D:\Destination\Files\"
End With

'Script Ends
```

Comment: The usual approach, assuming Windows, is to use Task Scheduler to run the script every few minutes.  The script detects a file, performs action, and if necessary records to a log (for example to avoid processing the same file again in the future).

Answer (score 1):

InstanceCreationEvent

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        .MoveFile "C:\Source\Files\*.*", "D:\Destination\Files\"
    End With
Loop
```

InstanceModificationEvent

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```

InstanceDeletionEvent

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am not an expert at VBS.  Please can you make appropriate changes to my given code above.

Comment: Thanks again. I do not wish to use Task Scheduler. The above "InstanceCreationEvent" is smart. But how do mate this creation event with my code above ?

Comment: I edited one of them. You are required to be a programmer (or wannabe one).

Comment: I am quite a slow wannabe programmer. Excuse me on this. I have been racking my brains, but haven't got an answer. please could you help and mate the two. Would really appreciate the help.

Comment: I edited the first sample code.