# Batch file auto copy files from USB/DVD to HDD - wait for USB/DVD to be inserted (detect it)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is my first `.bat` file. I want to make a script to copy all my files from USB or DVD/CD when volume is detected to hardisk.

I did not find something good. I think I need to implement something like this:

```
while(!volume:e /*if is DVD*/ || !volume:g /*if is USB*/)
    keep seeking
if(volume:e is detected)
xcopy e:\* d:\Backup\ /s /q
if(volume:g is detected)
xcopy g:\* d:\Backup /s /q
```

My final result:

```
:while
    if ("wmic logicaldisk where drivetype= '2' get volumename") NEQ "No Instance(s) Available."::HERE IS THE PROBLEM
(GOTO :Syntax) else (GOTO :while)
:Syntax
    xcopy e:\* d:\Backup\ /s /q

//Use DriveType=5 for DVDs
```

I don't know how to write after `NEQ`, because if no USB is connected cmd print `No Instance(s) Available.`, but don't work correct for what I want.

Please help me... what do I miss?

Comment: Since you already know what to implement, you should just try it; when you are stuck at a certain point, come back here, clearly describing the failure you are facing. Hint: to get the drive type, you could use the [`wmic` command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html), like `wmic LogicalDisk get Description,DeviceID,DriveType`...

Comment: You shoud try this vbscript instead [Script that detect usb when it is inserted and copy files from usb to computer
up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38445884/script-that-detect-usb-when-it-is-inserted-and-copy-files-from-usb-to-computer?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

This waits for a VolumeChangeEvent then copies c:\test onto the new volume.

```
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set evtDevice = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery ("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent")

Wscript.Echo "Waiting for events ..."
Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = evtDevice.NextEvent
    'report an event
    Wscript.Echo " Win32_Device Changed event occurred" & VBNewLine
    If objReceivedEvent.EventType = 1 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Config Changed" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 2 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Arrived" 

         Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Volume")
         For Each objItem in colItems
               If objitem.DriveType = 2 then
                        Wscript.Echo objItem.DriveType & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.driveletter

                        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
                        Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
                        set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

                        Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(objitem.driveletter)
                        Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace("c:\test\")
                        Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
                        DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
                        Wscript.Echo "Finished Copying"


               End If
        Next


    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 3 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Device Left" 
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 4 Then 
         Wscript.Echo "Type = Computer Docked" 
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: This must be a new version of Batch that I've never seen before. Is it included in Windows 10?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think it's VBScript
Error: http://imgur.com/Jf1oW99
I don't know VBScript or Batch, but Batch looks more simple.
Help...

Comment: That because you don't have a `c:\test` folder that it will copy files to. Create it. Batch can't wait for events.

Comment: @Noodles it's correct. I change `objitem.DriveType = 2` to `objitem.DriveType = 5` for CD-ROM but don't work. Why?

Comment: Because you are only changing discs perhaps. Try a second script monitoring the drive letter, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517836/trigger-a-vbscript-when-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder

Comment: @Noodles Work only if I connect USB, then copy from CD-ROM and USB (both). I read your post from link, but I don't understand too much.

Comment: VBScript. You cannot do this in batch unless you want to loop testing for when the root directory is available - See `if /?` as in `if exist G:\`, `goto /?`, and `timeout /?`.