# Excel VBA "listener-trigger"

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to create on VBA "trigger" program which can do real-time work if some flag happens (file, or schedule )?
 Like shadow process or something else

Comment: See these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118586/monitor-drive-using-vb-script

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517836/trigger-a-vbscript-when-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder

Comment: Apart from QHarr's links, you might consider using C++ or C# (.net) for this.  Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition is free.

Comment: I know about best solution but - I need to take an action in the Excel